# TexMaker lost ability to produce pdf files

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker

Ubuntu 12.10,
Texlive 2012.20120611-4,
TexMaker 3.4-1

I was trying to change my Texmaker configuration from `bibtex` to `biblatex` and instead managed to lose any ability to produce pdf files. I do not get any error except a file not found message.

I stupidly thought that I could just type in `biber %` or `biber %.bcf` and things would work. They did not.

Then I typed in `bibtex %.aux` which does not seem to work but somehow in the process I seem to have managed to mess up my ability to produce pdfs.

I am assuming that I need to open out file path (blue square on the right) and find the right command but I don't see anything obvious but I am a amateur at Linux.

dvi is working fine but ps is not but. since I have never used it, I don't know if that is a new thing or was always true.  I can produce pdf output from the tex file using TexWorks.

I have tried changing the Quick Build setting from pdflatex + View pdf to LatexMK + view PDF without success. I even used synaptics to do a complete removal and re-installation but with no luck.  It looks like some config files are kept since at least my recent file list was still there after the new installation.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: You have to say `biber %`, because `biblatex` is the name of the LaTeX package, while `biber` is the name of the program that takes the place of `bibtex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A related question, which may be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib

Comment: ARRH, I need a rest .  I meant to type biber not biblatex in the message. I used biber in TexMaker.  What I don't understand is why I lost pdflatex nor do I know how to get it back.  Thanks

Comment: Which command do you have for pdflatex in the configuration?

Comment: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex . I'm a Linux and Latex newbie so I hope this is what you wanted. Thanks

Comment: Well, nothing apparently wrong there. What happens if you try to run pdflatex on the document? (Tools --> PDFLaTeX, or the F6 key on the keyboard)

Comment: I'll be! It works.  It looks like I somehow managed to reset the default in the tool bar and never realised what I had done.  Thanks very much for curing the problem   So back to using biber vs bibtex.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more. I tried a minimal example, changed `bibtex %.aux` to `biber %.bcf` in the Texmaker config, compiled with either Latexmk-quickbuild, or F6-F11-F6 (keyboard shortcuts). Worked fine in both cases. The example I used was `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`. The file `biblatex-examples.bib` is included in TeX Live.